# Get document text from printjob in c#

Tags: c#, printing

I'd like to get the text from documents that were sent to network printers from the printer queue. Printing the contents of the printer spool file yields garbage, though. (I already had to give up my dream of capturing the JobStream itself on the fly, I read it in various sources that it's mostly null.) So, since I get a garbage output, I have a terrible suspicion: it is naive to think that characters get sent to a printer. Maybe it's just a bunch a coordinates and shade codes for black and white, or color codes for color printers. So is there any hope of acquiring the original text from the spool file or a printer jobstream?

Answer (score 0):

It sure looks like graphics data that is sent to the printer. So it is too late to capture in the print queue. What is needed here is a custom print driver. I found only proprietary solutions, though.